# How to remove links inside a specific class container (php scrape)?

Tags: php, web-scraping

I am using php to scrape a page.  How do I remove links from within divs that have a specific class while keeping the name displayed?

e.g.

```
<p>Our list of teachers:</p>
<div class="teacher"><a href="...">John Brown</a></div>
<div class="teacher"><a href="...">Peter Smith</a></div>
<div class="teacher"><a href="...">Jane Doe</a></div>
```

Thanks for any help,
Geoff

Answer (score 0):

[DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) (for parsing) and [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) (for selecting) will allow you to easily get that text.

Answer (score 0):

Use [PHPQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/), a way of manipulating the DOM in a JQuery like manner.

Answer (score 0):

phpQuery or [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) simplify this significantly. But to provide an answer with an actual example:

```
$dom = qp($html);  // or $url
foreach ($dom->find("div.teacher a") as $a) {
    $a->replaceWith( $a->text() );
}
$html = $dom->writeHTML();
```

Comment: Thanks this looks great.  I am not familiar with phpQuery -- what is involved in using it?  Is it merely a link to a library?

Comment: Yes, it's a library wrapper around DOMDocument (which itself is a bit cumbersome to use). phpQuery has the nicer documentation, but QueryPath allows to just write `qp($html)` which is why I prefer it. You need to download and include() either to make use of the compact function calls.

Comment: Thanks Mario, sorry for the belated answer, (but I had to put that on hold for a while.)  This is actually part of an existing script - is it possible to do without the phpQuery or QueryPath libraries - i.e., in plain php?

Comment: You will have to use the raw DOMDocument API then. That's just slightly more coding effort, in this case anyway.